# Lottery "Sum" forecasting

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I was wondering if anyone can provide some mathematical insights to forecasting the "SUM" in this link as a time series. It is an oscillatory, range bound and poisson distribution. How can Monte Carlo or other methods be applied?

http://sg.myfreepost.com/sgTOTO_analysispower.php?draws=60&fn0=notselected&fn1=notselected&fn2=Sum

Answer (score 1):

You cannot meaningfully forecast this: it is a random lottery draw.  The best you can do is work out the probability of a particular sum.

As far as I can tell it is the sum of $7$ numbers sampled without replacement from $1$ to $45$.  The minimum value is $28$ and the largest $294$. Ignoring the order in which the balls come out there are ${45 \choose 7}=45379620
$ possibilities (or $\frac{45!}{38!}=228713284800$ if you do take order into account).

As for the number of ways of getting a particular sum $s$, this is the number of partitions of $s$ into $7$ distinct parts each no more than $45$.  You can use generating functions or recurrences to find this, but I already have a [java applet to do this](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm).  For instance for the most likely outcome $s=161$ which turned up on 21 May 2012, choose

- "Partitions with distinct terms of:" 161
- "Exact number of terms:" 7
- "Each term no more than:" 45

then click on "calculate partitions" to get the answer $554256$ and so a probability of $\frac{554256}{45379620} \approx 0.0122$.

The equivalent for a sum of $81$ as in 6 February was $\frac{23573}{45379620} \approx 0.0005$.

Comment: Isn't Monte Carlo method used for forecasting brownian type bell curve distribution?

Comment: @shelagh: This is not a Brownian process.  There is a bell-shaped curve though it is not exactly normal. A simulation will give you approximate estimates of the probabilities while the calculations above are exact. Your choice.

Comment: Where can I find MC simulation in excel for this case?

Comment: If it is not really normal bell curve, then exact calculations may not be meaningful.

Comment: @shelagh: It is bell shaped but not precisely a normal distribution (in particular it is discrete and has a limited range). But since you can calculate the exact probabilities, that does not matter.

Comment: @Henry I just realized that you studied the same subject at the same college and university as me, and that you live about 30 minutes walk from my apartment. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Monte Carlo Simulation in Excel, you might want to check this out:
http://investexcel.net/670/geometric-brownian-motion-excel/

Not sure if it is directly applicable to your case, maybe others here can share their MC SIM resources(Excel or otherwise), I am curious too.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for something with forecasting (next value) feature not just MC simulation.

Comment: Well, maybe not next exact value, but rather a changing next period best 80 numbers moving range instead of always having 161+-40 as a fixed best range. And, I am not referring to moving average line or range.