# Keno Game: What percentage of the sum of 20 balls has a value of 210 to 695?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In the Keno game, a player starts by selecting 20 numbers from the numbers 1 to 80. What percentage of the sum of 20 balls has a value of 210 to 695?. I don't have an idea to solve this. May anyone gives me a hint to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Is the selection "with replacement"? Are the selection independent each other?

Comment: @tommik https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keno so uniformly at random without replacement.  The $210$ part of the question is therefore easy to handle

Comment: @tommik, Keno Game without replacement and no independent like Henry said

Comment: @Henry: "The 210 part of the question is therefore easy to handle " yes ahah

Comment: From random tests, it looks like the probability is around 0.1, or slightly higher. Here's a Sage / Python [histogram maker](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNT9FqAjEQfL-vGHxKINA7QbHigT-gP1BEYi-nATc5NhF_v5uklC6EIcPM7OzMkcA2TAKelsgZybnJIFlanq7rjj5kx_Y7d5ObQdYHxa-QxqHvDaiAIBfPeI7B6X0HGd71GEvu3anBYDfoRtMfS40pRlXt7T_ZbEXzlV6k6qs1lOQZrHutcRix_dxULebIuMIHydX4AP0j6o5SVF_wO9WzsNyjVidnw34lV8qKsrLYq7qVesS3eviU451tExjcfL1a6x_AY1ks&lang=python).

Comment: (cont) If you set `runs` or `m` to higher values, you'll get a better estimate, but if you set them too high and the code takes too long to run, the server may terminate the job without drawing the histogram.

Comment: @PM2Ring It is precisely $0.1025153$, up to rounding.  A normal approximation (with a continuity correction) is $0.10165$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related question: [Lottery "Sum" forecasting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148585/lottery-sum-forecasting)

The smallest possible draw is $1+2+\cdots +20 =210$, so this lower constraint does not really affect the calculation, but it does no harm.

The probability of getting a sum $s$ is the number of partitions of $s$ into $20$ distinct positive parts each not greater than $80$, divided by the number of ways of choosing $20$ numbers from $80$.  This partition number can be found with a recursion, where if $n$ is the number of parts and $k$ is the largest part:

$$r(s,n,k) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{s-k} r(s-i,n-1,i)$$ starting at $r(0,0,0)=1$.  Here we want $\sum\limits_{s=210}^{695} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{80} r(s,20,k)$.  The following R code does the recursion and finds the probability of $0.1025153$ (exact up to rounding)

```
library(matrixStats)
balls <- 80 
draws <- 20      # from 2 to balls-1

maxsum <- draws*(balls + (balls-draws+1))/2
partitions <- matrix(rep(0, balls*maxsum), ncol=balls)
partitions[cbind(1:(balls-draws+1), 1:(balls-draws+1))] <- 1 
cumpartitions <- rowCumsums(partitions)

for (nthdraw in 2:draws){
  for (thisdraw in nthdraw:(balls-draws+nthdraw )){
    partitions[, thisdraw] <- 
      c(rep(0, thisdraw), cumpartitions[1:(maxsum-thisdraw), thisdraw-1]) 
    }
  partitions[, 1:(nthdraw-1)] <- 0  
  cumpartitions <- rowCumsums(partitions)
  }

results <- cumpartitions[, balls]
c(sum(results), choose(balls, draws))  # check should be equal
# 3.535316e+18 3.535316e+18
sum(results[210:695]) / sum(results) # answer to the question
# 0.1025153
```

Other approaches include simulation, such as

```
set.seed(2021)
kenosum <- function(balls, drawn){sum(sample(balls, drawn))}
simdata <- replicate(10^6, kenosum(80, 20))
mean(simdata >= 210 & simdata  <= 695)
# 0.102791
```

which is quite close.

An alternative is a normal approximation.  The mean score is $\frac{20 \times 81}{2} = 810$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{20 \times (80-20) \times 81}{12}}=90$ so we could try about $\Phi\left(\frac{695+ \frac12-810}{90}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{210 -\frac12-810}{90}\right)$ or in R:

```
pnorm(695.5, 810, 90) - pnorm(209.5, 810, 90)
# 0.1016471
```

which is not too far away from the exact answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help!! But I'm not clear about all your solutions :'(. 
In your third solution, why is the normal approximation that can solve the problem, and in the `mean score` why 20x 81 when we have 80 balls?

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc A version of the central limit theorem (with a suitable rescaling/relocation) applies for a fixed proportion of balls drawn and increasing numbers of balls to draw from and drawn despite the slight lack of independence, because the distortion caused by that lack of independence weakens as the numbers increase.

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc For the mean, each ball drawn can be anything from $1$ to $80$ so has an expectation of $\frac{1+2+\cdots+80}{80}=\frac{81}{2}$ and there are $20$ of them so by linearity of expectation (no independence required) the mean of then is $20$ times this so $810$

Comment: thank you so much, I understand now.  And in your first solution, can you explain why `a recursion` can solve the problem or give me some keywords, I will find on the internet. Your first solution is stranger to me.